# Filtering Issue in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filter

Here is the code I have written to filter some items:

```
const SearchScreen = () => {
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
    const [results, setResults] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');


const searchApi = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
            params: {
                limit: 30,
                term,
                location: 'san jose'
            }
        });

        setResults(response.data.businesses);


    } catch (e) {
        setErrorMessage('Ooops!!! Something went wrong.')
    }
};

const filterResultsByPrice = price => {
    // price === '$' || '$$' || '$$$'
    return results.filter(result => {
      return result.price === price;
    });
  };


return (
    <View>
        <SearchBar term={term} onTermChange={setTerm} onTermSubmit={searchApi} />
        {errorMessage ? <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
        <Text>Total {results.length} results are found.</Text>


        <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice('$')} title="Cost Effective" />
        <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice('$$')} title="Bit Pricer" />
        <ResultsList results={filterResultsByPrice('$$$')} title="Ambanis Only" />

    </View>
);
```

};

I have been using this code and again and again I'm getting sometimes it works and sometime it throw this error on the terminal:

```
results.filter is not a function. (In 'results.filter(function (result) {
        return result.price === price;
      })', 'results.filter' is undefined)
```

Please help me resolving this. i am not able to find the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Although it run sometimes but generally throw this this error often. Tried cleared my cache using npm start -c command as well. But no use of clearing as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is when you initialize the results variable as a an empty string, so when you call filter() on a string you get an error.
Try to change the initialization to an empty array:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
```